# $N^TN=I_m$ and $A^TN=(A^TN)^T$

Tags: matrices, systems-of-equations, matrix-equations, symmetric-matrices

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$ ($n>m$). Does exist a matrix $N \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$ such that $N^TN=I_m$ and $A^TN=(A^TN)^T$. I easily found  examples of matrices $N$ with $N^TN=I_m$ or $A^TN=(A^TN)^T$ but none working for both.

I also tried to set equations for $n=3$ and $m=2$. For $A=\begin{bmatrix} a_1 & b_1 \\ a_2 & b_2 \\  a_3 & b_3 \\ \end{bmatrix}$ and $N=\begin{bmatrix} n_1 & m_1 \\ n_2 & m_2 \\  n_3 & m_3 \\ \end{bmatrix}$, we need to satisfy:
\begin{align*}
    \sum_{i=1}^3 n_i^2 &= 1 \\
    \sum_{i=1}^3 m_i^2 &= 1 \\
    \sum_{i=1}^3 n_im_i &=0 \\
    \sum_{i=1}^3 a_i n_i &= \sum_{i=1}^3b_i m_i
\end{align*}
but I can not conclude something since we have a set of non-linear equations.

Comment: Any matrix $A$ satisfies $A = QR$ for some orthogonal matrix $Q$ and upper triangular matrix $R$. Now, since $M = Q^TN$ satisfies $M^TM = I$ and $R^TM = M^TR$ if and only if $N$ satisfies $N^TN = I$ and $A^TN = N^TA$, we can without loss of generality assume $A$ is upper triangular.

Comment: Let $r=\text{rank}(A)$. If $n-r\geq m$ we can take $N$ to be any matrix whose columns consist of orthonormal vectors from $\text{Col}(A)^{\perp}$. That will do the trick, but this requires imposing some conditions on the dimension of $A$'s column space.

Comment: @MatthewH. Raises the question that if $n - r < m$, can we always take an orthonormal basis for $\mathrm{Col}(A)^\perp$ to be some of the vectors of $N$? Come to think of it, what are the constraints on the rank of $A^T N$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Let $A=USV^T$ be a compact/economic singular value decomposition over $\mathbb R$, so that $U$ has the same size as $A$ and it has orthonormal columns, $S$ is a square nonnegative diagonal matrix, and $V$ is an orthogonal matrix. Now take $N=UV^T$. Then $N$ has orthonormal columns and $A^TN=VSV^T$ is symmetric.